# How do I create multiple Java object instances from an array?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get this method to create two instances of the class 'Sport'. The method is passing in a array which has the information about the class which is then sent to the constructor to be created.

However, I'm unsure how to refer to instance 1 or 2 given my code.

```
public static void seperateValues(String sportDetail) {
  String[] sportDetails = sportDetail.split(",");
  System.out.println("Adding new sport to the Sport collection");
  System.out.println(sportDetail);
  /*
  for(int i=0; i<sportDetails.length; i++) //just used for testing whether it was splitting correctly {
    System.out.println(sportDetails[i]); 
  }*/
  //name,usagefee,insurance,affiliationfees, then court numbers
  //Tennis,44,10,93,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
  int vlength;
  vlength = sportDetail.length();
  new Sport(sportDetails); //this static methods loops twice, giving tennis and baseball
  System.out.println(name); //this lists tennis and baseball respectively
 }
```

Comment: "`//this static methods loops twice, giving tennis and baseball`", do you mean the `seperateValues()` method gets called in a loop somewhere else?

Comment: Which is the static method you are talking about in comment?

Comment: If all this method does in the end is create an object, why not get it to return that object so you can then refer to it wherever it was you called it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to refer to two instances of sport, you can simply do this:

```
Sport sport1 = new Sport(sportDetails);
Sport sport2 = new Sport(sportDetails);
```

And then simply call `sport1` or `sport2` when you want to access them, however if you want to use that method n number of times for n number of sports, you can do this:
First change the `separateValues()` method to return a sport, by changing these lines:

```
public static void seperateValues(String sportDetail) {
```

to

```
public static Sport seperateValues(String sportDetail) {
```

At the end of the method, make it return a sport, like this:

```
Sport sport = new Sport(sportDetails);
return sport;
```

And then you can call the method inside a loop and create a list, so you can create as many sports are you need:

```
//First declare a list of sports:
List<Sport> sports = null;

for (int i = 0; i<asManySportsAsYouWantToAdd; i++){
sports.add(separateValues(sportDetail));
}
```

And then, to access each individual sport, you can simple use:

```
sports.get(n); //Where n is place of the sport on the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original string `sportDetail` was "tennis,baseball", which then turned into an array of 2 terms, such as `sportDetails[0] = "tennis"` and `sportDetails[1] = "baseball"`, then within your class `Sport` you simply need to reference them as such.

In other words, `sportDetails[0]`.